# NiFi how do I pass an attribute to the executeScript processor

Tags: javascript, apache-nifi, execute-script

The flowfile uses evaluateJsonPath in order to extract values and setup my Attributes. I need to pass some of the attributes into a JavaScript function which I have in a ExecuteScript processor. The setting is for ECMAScript and the JS code is in the Script Body.

So, as an example if my attributes are A, B, C and my function is foo(arg){}

How do I call the function foo(A)?

I have tried putting at the end of the Script Body, after the declaration of my function foo

```
foo(A);
foo(${A});
```

But this keeps failing and I am not able to find any examples on how to pass in the value to the function call. I get either a "A is not defined in " or Expects a , and got a {.

What is the proper way to pass an Attribute to the ExecuteScript processor?

UPDATED: SEE BELOW

So as I'm trying to figure this out here is what I'm dealing with.

1. Read in a JSON file
2. Set some attributes with EvaluateJSONPath
3. HERE I NEED TO merge some attributes and want to use the ExecuteScript to run some JavaScript

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var flowFile = session.get();
if(flowFile){
  var argFoo = flowFile.getAttribute("someAttribute");
  
  // Set the value as a new Attribute in the flowFile
  session.putAttribute(flowFile, "NewAttribute", argFoo);
}
```

I've also tried things like

```
var flowFile = session.get();
if(flowFile){
  var argFoo = flowFile.getAttribute("someAttribute");

  // Create a new flowFile
  var newFlowFile = session.create(flowFile);
  // Set the value as a new Attribute in the flowFile
  session.putAttribute(newFlowFile, "NewAttribute", argFoo);
}
```

I'm blindly guessing how to get this to work.

Can someone point me in the right direction here on how to use JavaScript within this ExecuteScript processor?

The latest error is "*This FlowFile was not created in this session and was not transferred to any Relationship via ProcessSession.transfer()*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these sites:

- https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.20.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/additionalDetails.html
- https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-1/ta-p/248922
- https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-2/ta-p/249018
- https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ExecuteScript-Cookbook-part-3/ta-p/249148
- https://github.com/mkalika/nifi-executescript-samples

You don't have to create new a FlowFile, if you want only to add a new attribute.

**[Example](https://github.com/mkalika/nifi-executescript-samples/blob/master/src/test/resources/javascript/attributes.js)**

```
flowFile = session.get();
if (flowFile != null) {

    // Get attributes
    var greeting = flowFile.getAttribute("greeting");
    var message = greeting + ", Script!";

    // Set single attribute
    flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "message", message);

    // Set multiple attributes
    flowFile = session.putAllAttributes(flowFile, {
        "attribute.one": "true",
        "attribute.two": "2"
    });

    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
}
```

Comment: Your example helped me by validating what I had already done. The problem I discovered was due to 2 things. The data missing in the flowfile and things that were coded incorrectly in the script. I had to find and use a Groovy playground site to test out what was in the code to discover that several items were done incorrectly. Thanks for the links and the post.